# Using PHP to group and display MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

```
distID   distName   regID
1        Khulna      1
2        Shatkhira   1
3        Bagerhat    1
4        Pirojpur    1
5        Barishal    2
6        Barguna     2
7        Patuakhali  2
8        Bhola       2
9        Jhalokathi  2
```

Hi I have the above table, and I can display data properly. I need to group regID field in the output. How can I do this? below is my php code.

```
<?php
            include("db.php");


            $result=mysql_query("SELECT * from district d inner join region r on d.regID=r.regID");
        //  $result1=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM district"));
               // echo '<pre>';
                //print_r($result);

            while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {   //print_r($test);
                $id = $test['distID'];  
                echo "<tr align='center'>"; 
                echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$test['distName']."</font></td>";
                echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$test['regName']."</font></td>";
                echo"<td> <a href ='view.php?distID=$id'>Edit</a>";
                echo"<td> <a href ='del.php?distID=$id'><center>Delete</center></a>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }
            mysql_close($conn);
            ?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What is your **problem** in above code? Why you need grouping of `regid`?

Comment: What should the output look like?

Answer (score -1):

add GROUP BY reqID at the end of  your query.

It will only return 1 and 2 however.

Answer (score -1):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * from district d inner join region r on d.regID=r.regID GROUP BY r.regID");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add `GROUP BY` whatever you want,

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * from district d inner join region r on d.regID=r.regID GROUP BY `regID`");
```